# Is there a notification that gets sent when iPad Dock appears?

Tags: ios, ipad, dock

I can't find any documentation on the iPad Dock and whether the app gets notified when it appears or disappears. If you continue pulling the Dock after it is visible the task switcher appears and `applicationWillResignActive` method gets called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question, although specifically with regards to touches in progress when the dock appeared. `touchesEnded:` doesn't get called when the dock appears, which was messing up some logic I had for managing the user holding their finger in a certain area.

However, I later found out that when the dock appears, the method `touchesCancelled:` gets called instead of `touchesEnded:`, which I could use to clean up my hold handling and I didn't actually need to know when the dock appears.

Note that `touchesCancelled:` also gets called when things randomly appear on the screen, such as calls and alerts.

Hopefully this was similar to your issue.